# 8 questions on true/false quiz. Expected number of correct answers with a given probability of correct answer of a question "i".

Tags: probability

The odds/probability of a correct answer of question $i$ is $p=1-2^{-i}$

What is the expected number of correct answers?

My attempt:

$$(1-2^{-1})\cdot
(1-2^{-2})\cdot
(1-2^{-3})\cdot
(1-2^{-4})\cdot
(1-2^{-5})\cdot
(1-2^{-6})\cdot
(1-2^{-7})\cdot
(1-2^{-8})\cdot= 0.28991911785$$

$$0.28991911785 \cdot 8 = 2.3193529428$$

$$= 2 \text{ questions correct}$$

Comment: Do you know the definition of expected value? It is probably a good start...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for showing your work.

Your fisrt line computes the probability that *all* answers are correct. 
The expected number of correct answers is not just $8$ times this probability.

Think of it differently: The expected number $E_i$ of correct answers you get from question $i$ is simply $p_i=1-2^{-i}$ (more completely, it is $1\cdot p+0\cdot(1-p)$). The expected number of correct answers of the whole quiz is then $E=E_1+\ldots + E_8$.

Comment: (more completely, it is 1⋅p+0⋅(1−p).   How is this achieved?

Comment: @DavidP. That was meant to reflect the definition of expected value $E(X)=\sum_k x_k(P(X=x_k)$ more properly, here with $P(X=1)=p$ and $P(X=0)=1-p$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, This problem is harder than it seems. He may to calculate P(one correct answer).  This could happen in 8 ways. One of the ways is 1C,2W,3W,4W,5W,6W,7W, and 8W.  Each one will have a probability that it is correct or incorrect.  You have to multiply as they are independent.  You got to do such thing 7 more times for just one question to be correct. Then you have 28 different combinations of two questions being right and so on for 3,4,5,6,7,8 questions to be correct.  Then you take the expectation of each probability mulitiplied by the  number of correct.  Am I right?

Comment: @satishramanathan That's a complicated way of computing the reuslt. Seeing that expectations can simply be added, makes the computation much simpler. Moreover, the problem statement does *not* say that the events are independant; hence your proposed method may not be adequate. Additivity of expectations does not need independence.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, you example of number correct answer being 1 and being 0 is correct.  How would you treat it for number of correct answers being 2?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, is the logic of expected number of correct answers you get from question 2 is $1-\frac{1}{4}$. and hence you simply add the probabilities and you get and answer of 7.something.  WOuld it be the way to go?

Comment: @satishramanathan Yes. It seems that you did exactlythat calculation in EXCEL

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, I did the complicated way and confirmed that the answer is the same. Sorry for the confusion.  Thanks for clarifying my doubt.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is finding the probability of getting all the answers correctly given the independent probability.

In this case you have to add all the independent probabilities to get the answer:

= (1 - 1/2) + (1 - 1/4) + (1 - 1/8) + (1 - 1/16) + (1 - 1/32) + (1 - 1/64) + (1 - 1/128) +

(1 - 1/256)

= 1/2 + 3/4 + 7/8 + 15/16 + 31/32 + 63/64 + 127/128 + 255/256

=  7.0039062 to be precise.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have given it as an EXCEL Sheet with probabilities and summation.

Hope it helps